# What kind of antenna is this?

Tags: identification, antenna

Is it even an antenna? I assumed it was an antenna because the stuff around the base looks like what I've seen around cell towers, but it doesn't look like a cell tower.

It was modified between 2015 and 2017. Location: 44.07827° N, 123.12016° W

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The antenna displayed is a simple loaded Marconian dipole.

Comment: looks kind of like an MDS antenna, but the date is wrong for that technology,.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cellphone base station antenna / mast.

Here's another [cellphone base station antenna](https://www.greenwichtime.com/news/article/New-cell-tower-approved-despite-community-1472340.php#photo-1125640), disguised as a flag pole, on Ritch Avenue West in Byram, Connecticut.

[image]